# Index of subgroup generated by characters induced from $p$-elementary subgroups in the ring of virtual characters

Tags: rt.representation-theory, induced-representations, character-theory

I posted this over on MSE, but received absolutely no love. So maybe I’ll have better luck here. It seems like a relatively easy group theory question that I’m just not seeing! It’s on the essential part of the proof of Brauer’s Induction Theorem:

Let $G$ be a finite group and $R(G) =  \Bbb Z\chi_1\oplus \cdots \oplus\Bbb Z\chi_h$ be the ring of virtual characters of $G$, so $\{\chi_i\}_{i=1}^h$ is the set of all irreducible characters of $G$. Let $p$ be prime, and let $V_p$ denote the subgroup of $R(G)$ generated by characters induced from $p$-elementary subgroups of $G$.

In *Linear Representations of Finite Groups*, Chapter 10, Serre shows that if the order of $G$ is $p^n\ell$ with $(p,\ell)=1$, then $\ell\in V_p$.

He then says that this is enough to show that the index $[R(G):V_p]$ is finite and relatively prime to $p$.

That the index is finite is clear: Since $V_p$ is an ideal of $R(G)$, then $\ell R(G)\leq V_p$, and since 
$$\infty > \ell h = [R(G): \ell R(G)] = [R(G): V_p][V_p:\ell R(G)],$$
is follows that $[R(G): V_p]<\infty$. (Recall that we said $h$ is the number of irreducible characters of $G$).

However, the equality
$$[R(G): V_p] = \frac{\ell h}{[V_p:\ell R(G)]} $$
does not in itself guarantee that $[R(G): V_p]$ is prime to $p$, as far as I see. So, why does $\ell\in V_p$ imply $[R(G): V_p]$ is prime to $p$?

Comment: By the way, $[R(G):\ell R(G)]$ is $\ell^{h},$ not $\ell h$. Since the former is coprime to $p$, but the latter might not be, this might be the source of your difficulty.